# How to monitor HTTP status codes with serverless datadog plugin

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, datadog

I am using [serverless-plugin-datadog](https://github.com/DataDog/serverless-plugin-datadog), which uses [datadog-lambda-layer](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/datadog-lambda-layer/) under the hood.

The [docs state](https://github.com/DataDog/serverless-plugin-datadog/blob/master/README.md#how-it-works), that by using this plugin it is not necessary to wrap a handler anymore. This is, by the way, the main reason why I decided to go for it.

The lambda itself is a REST API, which responds with dedicated status codes.

My question now is, how can I monitor the number of `4xx` and `5xx` http status codes? Do I have to define custom metrics in datadog for this to work? I was under the assumption that the plugin comes with those data out-of-the-box, but it looks like I'm missing an important part here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but it looks like I'm missing an important part here.

That was the point. The lambda itself has not much todo with particular `statusCodes`. So I either may log each status code and let datadog parse it accordingly.

Or, that's the solution I went for, I can leverage API-Gateway for monitoring status codes per lambda.